# Barra de progreso con texto dinamico

Tags: html5, css3, angularjs

tengo una barra de progreso que he creado con HTML5, CSS3 y AngularJS, pero no sé muy bien cómo meter texto dinámico, es decir, que de 0 a 33% debajo de la barra muestre un texto, del 34% al 66% otro y otro del 65% al 100% (los textos a mostrar son los que pongo a continuación en el código de validando y guardar)

**HTML**
este es el HTML de la barra de progreso con los 3 div con los textos a mostrar dinamicamente

```
<!--barra progreso-->
<div data-ng-if="manageDesignResourcesView.pintarBarra" style="position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100vh;z-index: 10">
    <div style="background-color: #010d1e;opacity: .3; width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>
    <div class="row _top20 _bottom20" style="position: absolute;align-items: center;top: 40%;left: 33%;width: 35%; background-color: #fff;">
        <div class="antetitulo _bottom15" style="margin: 1rem 2rem">
            <h3 class="tit-titular-antetitulo-2-nivel" data-translate>
                manageDesignResources-en-proceso</h3>
            <div class="_border-solid-bottom-E1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col12" style="margin: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;">
            <div class="barra-progreso _w100">
                <div class="caja_gris">
                    <div class="caja_azul"
                        ng-style="{'width': manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.proceso+'%'}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>Validando campos de entrada</div>
            <div>Validando campos de salida</div>
            <div>guardando campos</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ANGULARJS**
esta es la función de carga de la barra de progreso

```
//EL PARAMETRO AVANCE SERÁ EL QUE RECOJA EL % DE AVANCE DEL PROCESO.
        $scope.move = function(avance, mensaje) {
            var widthBarra  = 1;
            //SIMULACION PARA MAQUETA
            var avanceProceso = $interval(frame,20);
            function frame () {
                if (widthBarra == 100) {                   
                    $interval.cancel(avanceProceso);
                    $scope.manageDesignResourcesView.pintarBarra = false;
                
                }else if(widthBarra < 100){
                    widthBarra++;
                    $scope.manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.proceso = widthBarra;
                }
            }
            
        }
```

No se si lo tendría que hacer en AngularJS, crear las variables con los textos y crear varios `else if` y ahí insertar los textos según el progreso y meter la variable en el HTML.

Alguien me podría ayudar para poder mostrar bien los textos dinamicamente??

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

He insertado en el JS dentro del if de la carga de la barra de progreso, se insertan el if y else if correspondientes con las variables del texto

```
 //EL PARAMETRO AVANCE SERÁ EL QUE RECOJA EL % DE AVANCE DEL PROCESO.
        $scope.move = function(avance, mensaje) {
            var widthBarra  = 1;
            //SIMULACION PARA MAQUETA
            var avanceProceso = $interval(frame,20);
            function frame () {
                if (widthBarra == 100) {                   
                    $interval.cancel(avanceProceso);
                    $scope.manageDesignResourcesView.pintarBarra = false;
                
                } else if(widthBarra < 100){
                    widthBarra++;
                    $scope.manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.proceso = widthBarra;
                    if(widthBarra < 33) {
                        $scope.manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.txt_progreso = "Recuperando catálogo..."
                    } else if(widthBarra > 33 && widthBarra < 66){
                        $scope.manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.txt_progreso = "Finalizando catálogo..."
                    } else if(widthBarra > 66 && widthBarra < 100){
                        $scope.manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.txt_progreso = "guardando catálogo..."
                    }
                    
                } 
            }
            
        }
```

y en el HTML en el div donde se inserta el texto, pongo la variable correspondiente `{{manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.txt_progreso}}`, es decir el HTML quedaría así

```
<div data-ng-if="manageDesignResourcesView.pintarBarra" style="position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100vh;z-index: 10">
    <div style="background-color: #010d1e;opacity: .3; width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>
    <div class="row _top20 _bottom20" style="position: absolute;align-items: center;top: 40%;left: 33%;width: 35%; background-color: #fff;">
        <div class="antetitulo _bottom15" style="margin: 1rem 2rem">
            <h3 class="tit-titular-antetitulo-2-nivel" data-translate>
                manageDesignResources-en-proceso</h3>
            <div class="_border-solid-bottom-E1"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col12" style="margin: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;">
            <div class="barra-progreso _w100">
                <div class="caja_gris">
                    <div class="caja_azul"
                        ng-style="{'width': manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.proceso+'%'}">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>{{manageDesignResourcesFunctionality.txt_progreso}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```